# modrewrite redirects for URLs with arguments

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

Question about 301 redirect / modrewrite

I know there are a lot of topics on this subject but so far I have not managed to create my needed redirect.

here is my current URL : `mysite.net/doc.php?title=john`

needs to redirect to : `mysite.net/doc.php?renamed=john&id=3340`

so I am adding 'id' and renaming the variable 'title'.

Does anyone know if this can actually be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
"/docs.php?title=^([^/]+)"  "http://new.example.com/docs/renamed=$1&id=3340"  [L]
```

**Rewriting For Certain Query Strings**

Rewrite URLs like http://example.com/page1?title=val to http://example.com/page2?var=val but don't rewrite if val isn't present.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} val
RewriteRule ^/page1 /page2?renamed=$1&id=3340

Comment: thanks so much stackfull. Im going to look at this now. Do you know if i can put any number of modrewrite in my htaccess file ?  or should just put a dedicated htaccess file in the applicable directory ?

Comment: also my 'id' argument is also a variable related to 'renamed' variable. Do you know how i should amend your code ?

Comment: Hi  alankeys, please visit this URL [link]http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html and check rewrite query string section

Comment: You can use this query base url, so in your case title be a query string then write redirect url

Comment: Havent managed to solve yet Stackfull.    Should you base URL be as follows.....    "http://new.example.com/doc.php?renamed=$1&id=3340"  [R,L]

Comment: Try new added answers and let me know

Comment: Here is my actual code....  RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule "^/share-charts.php?Symbol1=^([^/]+)" "http://www.example.co.uk/stock-charts/share-charts.php?epic-code=$1&id=4343"  [L]

Comment: RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule "^/share-charts.php?Symbol1=^([^/]+)" "http://www.example.co.uk/stock-charts/share-charts.php?epic-code=$1&id=4343"  [L]

Comment: trying to rewrite to....  http://www.example.co.uk/stock-charts/ /share-charts.php ?epic-code=$1&id=4343

Comment: hi use it direct 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} val "http://new.example.com/docs/renamed=$1&id=3340" [L]

Comment: I don't have any tool that checks it but how its work now

Comment: stackfull. many thanks for all your ideas... i will try again with rewritecond and when i get the solution shall post it here for everyones benefit. thanks again for helpful pointers....